# Pandas/Matplotlib: How to change scale of x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I checked out some tutorials regarding plotting. If I understood it correct so far, I tried to create a plot via the matplotlib module within pandas. For that I created a df with a count and timespan index:

My dataframe (I want to analyze the amount of quotes per quarter, therefore I created an other df for the first quarter and so on):

```
count_second_quarter = second_quarter.groupby("request_date").count()
count_second_quarter

request_date     quote_id   count
        
2019-04-01        94        94
2019-04-02        123       123
2019-04-03        423       423
2019-04-04        123       123
2019-04-05        312       312
... ... ...
```

Then I created a first plot:

```
plt.plot(count_first_quarter['count'])
plt.plot(count_second_quarter['count'])
```

[image]

First question, I think I am mixing matplotlib and pandas up.
How can I change the scale of the x-axis?
Ideally, I want to have one plot and for each quarter a separate line..

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in describing the desired output?

Comment: "I want to have one plot and for each quarter a separate line" <- doesn't your current figure already do this?

Comment: Thanks! The idea is to analyze, how does the amount of quote change over the period of one quarter. So one question would be, are there as many quote at the end of quarter 1 as of quarter 3? Therefore, I would like to plot the amount of quotes for each quarter in a let`s say 90 days time frame. Hope that makes it a little bit clearer :)

Comment: And how could make the scale of my x-axis more granular? I mean I have data points for nearly every day..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `.reset_index()` before plotting. This will make the x-axis start from 0 to 89, you can update it using `plt.xticks()`

```
plt.plot(count_first_quarter.reset_index()['count'])
plt.plot(count_second_quarter.reset_index()['count'])
# update xticks
plt.xticks(range(90), range(1,91)
# update xlabel
plt.xlabel('Days')
# show legend
plt.legend(['Q1', 'Q2'])
```